# AWS API gateway, get and post with same name and different parameters

Tags: aws-api-gateway, openapi

I am trying to create an API that has a get and post endpoint with the same name but different parameters. My open API yaml file has:

```
paths:
  /jobs/{jobID}:
    get:
     .
     .
     .
  /jobs/{portfolioCode}:
    post:
     .
     .
     .
```

When I load it to the API gateway I get:

`Unable to create resource at path '/jobs/{portfolioCode}': A sibling ({jobID}) of this resource already has a variable path part -- only one is allowed`

Is what I am trying to do not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't create two resources with same path or similar pattern, not just in API Gateway, but generally in rest api specification anywhere.

For a client `/jobs/{jobID}` and `/jobs/{portfolioCode}` are exactly same when they call as `/jobs/100` for example.

So, we need to define one resource say `/jobs/{someId}` with multiple methods under it.

```
  /jobs/{id}:
    get:
      summary: Get Method
       ......
    post:
      summary: post method
      parameters:
       ......
```

Comment: OK thanks - I thought because one was a get and one a post they could be different.